# How to do text classification with DeepPavlov

Tags: nlp, artificial-intelligence, chatbot

I am interested in doing text classification with [DeepPavlov](http://deeppavlov.ai) chatbot framework.

The problem is I don't have enough training data. Ideally, I would like to do text classification with just few samples for each class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check out [DeepPavlov's](http://deeppavlov.ai) [autoFAQ models](https://github.com/deepmipt/DeepPavlov/blob/master/deeppavlov/configs/faq/). There models were specifically developed to be effective when training data is limited.

There are few models at your disposal

- tf-idf based models
- fastText models
- and mix of both

Change the dataset source in the configuration file and train the model by running

```
python -m deeppavlov train tfidf_logreg_en_faq
```

You can interact with the trained model either via a command line

```
python -m deeppavlov interact tfidf_logreg_en_faq -d
```

or via the Python code

```
from deeppavlov.core.commands.infer import build_model
faq = build_model("tfidf_logreg_en_faq", load_trained = True, download = True)
a = faq(["I need help"])
a
```

You can find all required code snippets in the [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1AJMXgnAZ1PyPM4sDLIpk7mNqhQx0lRSe)